# If statements with nested grain returns nothing

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to write an if statement based on a nested grain. I have tried this statement in multiple different ways:

```
System Services Needed:
  module.run:
    - name: service.systemctl_reload
    - onchanges:
      - file: /lib/systemd/system/salt-minion.service
      {% if salt['grains.get']('Project:DeviceTypeID') == '2' %}
      - file: /etc/rc.local
      - file: /opt/interfaces_init.sh
      {% endif %}
```

Returns:
`Rendering SLS 'Development:System' failed: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'Project:DeviceTypeID'`

```
System Services Needed:
  module.run:
    - name: service.systemctl_reload
    - onchanges:
      - file: /lib/systemd/system/salt-minion.service
      {% if grains['Project']['DeviceTypeID'] == '2' %}
      - file: /etc/rc.local
      - file: /opt/interfaces_init.sh
      {% endif %}
```

```
System Services Needed:
  module.run:
    - name: service.systemctl_reload
    - onchanges:
      - file: /lib/systemd/system/salt-minion.service
      {% if grains['Project:DeviceTypeID'] == '2' %}
      - file: /etc/rc.local
      - file: /opt/interfaces_init.sh
      {% endif %}
```

As you can tell from the example their are multiple device type IDs. In this example DeviceTypeID = 2 I need to worry about rc.local and a shell script. I can not seem to get this work for the life of me. I know the grain exists as I can run the following:

```
sudo salt 'Dev-Box' grains.get Project
```

and I will get:

```
Dev-Box:
    DeviceTypeID:
        1
    IsActive:
        True
    SoftwareEnvironmentName:
        Production
    SoftwareVersion:
        Foo
```

This is either a bug or I am missing something (significantly more likely I am missing something). Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 1: 
Added `['grains.get']('Project:DeviceTypeID')` example

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423009/how-to-compared-a-nested-pillar-key-value-in-an-if-statement-in-jinja2-for-salts

Comment: I don't believe this to be true. These are each key value pairs not lists, looks like the pillars being lists are the issue in that link, in my example the grains are in a dictionary in key value pairs with no lists.

Comment: I don't have a machine at had to test this, could you try something like:
{% if grains['Project:DeviceTypeID'] == '2' %}
just a guess, sorry

Comment: Nah no worries, I believe I have tried that but I did it again just in case, got the following: failed: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'Project:DeviceTypeID'

Comment: You're lacking a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 0):

in salt grains.get return a dictionary in the following format:
{'minion-id': value}
I believe if you change your code into something like bellow, it should works.

```
{% if salt['grains.get']('Project:DeviceTypeID')[minion-id] == '2' %}
```

Comment: That appears to be a no go. No syntax errors just does not run the if statement. I will add a quick else and see if it is even running the statement.

Comment: try this one:
{% if grains['Project']['DeviceTypeID'] == '2' %}

Comment: if that didn't work, please send the result of {%- do salt.log.error( grains['Project'] ) -%}

Comment: ```{%- do salt.log.error( grains['Project'] ) -%}``` Returns nothing. I was unaware this was available to me so maybe I am using it wrong. I just placed it above my if statement. I see no output from it though. Any ideas what is going on here? Everything else runs, and I do call grains in other areas of my state config and they for sure work.

Comment: OK then check if the grain is actually set. get grains.items and see if the there is a project key in grains

Comment: I can confirm grains.items returns the Project grains. The original post also has the output of ```sudo salt 'Dev-Box' grains.get Project```.

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting the correct minion? because that should show the grain! get `{%- do salt.log.error( grains['id'] ) -%}` and make sure of targeting

Comment: Is this supposed to output to console if I run a state or highstate? I am wondering if I am missing something. I added that just above the if statement and I see no return in the highstate or state.

Comment: Honestly at this point it seems like it is not rendering Jinja at all is it possible I have missed something that is preventing me from rendering Jinja?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible to not render jinja in sls files. if salt can not render sls files it throws an error. if you want, share your sls file here to find the problem

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought. I had to sanitize some of it but its all still there, I also put it in a pastebin for simplicity.  https://pastebin.com/51nyVt8w

Comment: I am not sure about `salt['grains.get']('Project:DeviceTypeID')` syntax. replace all of them with `grains['Project']['DeviceTypeID']`. one thing I found annoying in Salt is if there is some kind of nonsense in a valid salt format, it won't raise an error. I had problems like this before and I think this maybe is your problem too.

Comment: Ii feel like I must have run into a bug as your suggestions all look like they should work, and I tried so many different ways of writing the if statements. Still a no go.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do:

```
salt 'Dev-Box' grains.get 'Project:DeviceTypeID'
```

Then you don't actually have the proper grain set.

Try the following:

```
salt 'Dev-Box' grains.setval Project '{"DeviceTypeID": 2, "IsActive": True, "SoftwareEnvironmentName": "Production", "SoftwareVersion": "Foo"}'
```

Then the following state:

```
Do the {{ salt['grains.get']('Project:DeviceTypeID') }} things:
  test.succeed_with_changes:
    - some: thing
```

You should get:

```
      ID: Do the 2 things
Function: test.succeed_with_changes
  Result: True
 Comment: Success!
 Started: 17:10:42.739240
Duration: 0.491 ms
 Changes:
          ----------
          testing:
              ----------
              new:
                  Something pretended to change
              old:
                  Unchanged
```

---

Given [what you wrote elsewhere](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/54710)

```
salt Dev-Box grains.setval BETTI "{'DeviceTypeID': 2, 'IsActive': True SoftwareEnvironmentName': 'Production', 'SoftwareVersion': 'Foo'}"
```

Your problem is that you have `'` and `"` confused.

Wrapping the value with `"` makes it a string. Wrapping it with `'` and providing valid JSON makes it a dictionary value.

Comment: On your last point with the mixing up of ' and " I feel the need to disagree. I could be wrong but in this case the usage should be interchangeable. All that matters is that I pass the multiple key value pairs quoted. I would agree with you if salt 'Dev-Box' grains.get 'Project:DeviceTypeID' did not return the correct value, but it does. Sorry this took so long to come back around to.

Comment: @DaemonSlayer2048 I'm not sure you're accurate there. I'll have to try again, but the behavior I was seeing is that I was getting things that looked like they were correct, but they weren't. ' is not a valid JSON string - I could be wrong that it's parsing as JSON. Did you try changing your string? You still aren't showing how you're setting the grains. You can actually try my example out to see.